# Thinking in Sets #2

Tags: sql, t-sql, set

I need some help thinking in sets.  I have two queries that work.  They give me SET1 and SET2.  Now, for each row in SET1, I need to apply a different date from SET2 to get the final result SET3.

SET1
Our company serves clients who often miss appointments.  I have a complex query that results in a set of clients who missed appointments in the last six months ('No_Show') and this query counts the number of No_Shows for each client in the set.

```
SELECT client_id, COUNT(events.id) AS 'No_Show' 
FROM events
WHERE client_id IN 
(/*Complex SELECT statement here that works great*/) 
GROUP BY client_id
```

SET2
Now, I need to up the ante and show how many of these No_Show events occured since the last kept appointment with the client's primary clinician.

```
SELECT MAX(e_date)
FROM events e INNER JOIN client c ON e_client_id = client_id
WHERE e.event_staff_id = c.id_of_primary_clinician
```

To summarize, I want to run query two for each row in query one.

SET3
Finally, I need to show the number of No_Shows since the max-date.  So, for each row in SET1 I need to take the date from SET2 and count the number of No_Shows to get SET3.  Thank for your help!

Comment: I think it would have been easier if you had added some sample data and your expected output in a tabular format

Comment: client_id, COUNT(No_Shows)
123abc, 7
456xyz, 11
789opq, 4

Comment: are either or both of these tables involved in calculating SET1? [events] , [client] if yes to both than there is a good chance it can be done together, if just one is already used there is still a reasonable chance it can be done together. I'd like to see the "SELECT statement here that works great".

Answer (score 0):

Using a *correlated subquery*, something like:

```
SELECT OE.client_id, COUNT(OE.id) AS 'Recent_No_Show' 
  FROM events as OE
  WHERE OE.client_id IN 
    (/*Complex SELECT statement here that works great*/) and OE.e_date >
    ( SELECT MAX(e_date)
      FROM events e INNER JOIN client c ON e.client_id = c.client_id
      WHERE e.event_staff_id = c.id_of_primary_clinician and e.client_id = oe.client_id )
  GROUP BY OE.client_id
```

I assumed that you have a minor typo with `e_client_id`.